# Django Generic Edit Views To Accept An Instance

Tags: python, django

given that I have a Version model which References product model, how can I create generic create or update views that uses an instance of the Product model in the form given this url:

```
url(r'^product/(?P<pk>\d+)/create_version', ProductVersionCreateView.as_view(), name='workspace_product_create_version'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use django's Generic views.

### urls.py

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView, CreateView
#strongly recommend creating a views.py and putting this logic in there.     
class ProductVersionCreateView(CreateView):
    model  = ProductVersion
    def get_initial(self):
        return {"key": value} #dictionary for initial.
class ProductVersionUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ProductVersion

urlpatterns += url(r'^product/create_version', ProductVersionCreateView.as_view(), name='workspace_product_create_version'), #no primary key needed
urlpatterns += url(r'^product/(?P<pk>\d+)/update_version', ProductVersionEditView.as_view(), name='workspace_product_create_version'),
```

The docs are a little week in this area but I'd read them anyway.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/